# My silverlight application can't reach my WCF service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, silverlight

I develloped a WPF application that communicate with a WCF service trough a Portable Class Library, it works fine.

Now, i try to use the same library on a silverlight project, but the silverlight application cant communicate with the WCF service.
I set breakpoints on my WCF service, and when i use it with the silverlight application, there are never hit.

Edit:

Here is a method from my library calling my service:

```
public int CheckUser(string login, string password)
 {
     return this._client.EndCheckUser(_client.BeginCheckUser(login, password, null, null));
 }
```

The silverlight application is blocked in the EndCheckUser function, waiting for the answer of the service, because the service never receive the request from the application.

I tried to turn my service off, and the silverlight keep the same behaviour when it tries to call the method, no exception, just blocked in the end function.

And by the way, my Silverlight application is hosted in a WebSite.

Any ideas?
Thank in advance !

Comment: Add more description of what you've tried when attempting to connect your silverlight project to your WCF service. Seems like it could be something to do with configuration or possibly security.

Comment: I add more informations about my problem.

Comment: Did you add the async targeting pack for SL5 and a RIA services link pointing to your wcf service?

Comment: Do you have a [ClientAccessPolicy.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff797957.aspx) in your site root?